# Python's pycrypto library for random number generation vs os.urandom

Tags: python, random, pycrypto

I was trying to understand and figure out if I should use `os.urandom()` or `Crypto.Random.new()` for cryptographically secure pseudo-random numbers.

The following website seems to suggest to use `os.urandom()`:

https://github.com/mozilla/PyHawk/pull/13

but I don't really see why and the other websites I found online don't really explain which one to use.

If anyone knows which one is secure for cryptographic use, I would appreciate the advice!

One of the things that specifically worry me is that, I plan to use it to generate random numbers but I am worried that one day I generate some random numbers and the next day the state of the generator is the same and it starts to generate the same "random" numbers.

Comment: @U2EF1 For something as important and hard-to-verify as correctness of a CSPRNG, you'll have to provide a bit more than an offhand assertion.

Comment: [`ssl.RAND_bytes()` docs](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/ssl.html#ssl.RAND_bytes) recommend to read [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator) to get the requirements of a CSPRNG.

Comment: my specific worry is that, I plan to use these to generate random numbers but I am worried that one day I generate some and the next day the state of the generator is the same or something and it generates the same "random" (not really) numbers.

Comment: You may want to have a look: https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#module-secrets

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the link you gave, the *only* reason given to prefer `urandom()` is that it pulled less code in (the OS implements "most of it", and `os.urandom()` is built in to Python).

If you're going to distribute a Python package, you can simplify users' lives by minimizing external dependencies.  That's the entire point of the link you found.

In terms of quality, either way should work fine.  I prefer `urandom()` because I understand what it does; I never dug into the guts of `PyCrypto`.  But `urandom()` has been criticized for use in *some* environments.  [Click this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random) and scroll down to the part that starts

> Gutterman, Pinkas, & Reinman in March 2006 published a detailed
>   cryptographic analysis of the Linux random number generator ...

Answer (score 11):

I go for `os.urandom`. On all (recent) Python implementations I checked, it does the correct thing by simply opening an *unbuffered* connection to `/dev/urandom` or the equivalent device on other non-Linux platforms.

On the other hand, PyCrypto's `Crypto.Random` is a very complex wrapper based on Fortuna. Such complex construction was probably done in the hope of mitigating some flaws of the underlying OS. Unfortunately:

- It still pulls entropy from `/dev/urandom` (on Linux), so if the OS is broken, PyCrypto's `Crypto.Random` will be broken too (defeating its purpose)
- That choice has backfired, since it is very hard to deal with forking and cases where the same entropy gets reused by different processes (see [CVE-2013-1445](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2013-1445)).
- The Fortuna code is not covered at all by unit tests and Fortuna algorithm itself does not come with test vectors. That alone forces you to make a (big) leap of faith.

Answer (score 4):

`urandom` *does* return cryptographically secure numbers, with a caveat. If it runs out of entropy (real random data generated by mouse movement, CPU temperature fluctuations on Ivy Bridge+ chips, etc), it will start producing less secure pseudo-random numbers. These are generated by a strong generator, but depending on your application they may not be random enough. On Unix systems, `/dev/random` will block while waiting for more entropy, while `/dev/urandom` will start generating pseudo-random numbers.

I'm not knowledgeable on PyCrypto, however on reading the source, it seems the `Crypto/Random/OSRNG/posix.py` simply reads from `/dev/urandom` - so I wouldn't worry too much about the choice.

Answer (score 0):

From **Python 3.6**, the [**secrets**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html) module, which is based on `os.urandom` and `random.SystemRandom`, is the suggested secured random number generator.

> Warning: Note that the pseudo-random generators in the random module should NOT be used for security purposes. Use secrets on Python 3.6+ and os.urandom() on Python 3.5 and earlier.

[PEP 506](https://peps.python.org/pep-0506/) has a detailed discussion on this.